# Unable to start mongod service in 5.0 and connect to mongoshell

Tags: mongodb

Unable to start mongod service in 5.0 and connect to mongo shell:

systemctl start mongod.service and tail the log, I see that process is getting killed. 
Not sure what has changed in 5.0, I tried stopping the service, deleting the data directory and starting the instance which is not working.

```
    s:"I""c":"CONTROL""id":20698 "ctx":"-" msg:"***** SERVER RESTARTED *****"}
    
    s:"I""c":"RECOVERY"  "id":23987 "ctx":"initandlisten" msg:"WiredTiger recoveryTimestamp" attr:{"recoveryTimestamp":{"$timestamp":{"t":0 i:0}}}}        
    s:"D1"  "c":"COMMAND""id":23098 "ctx":"WTIdleSessionSweeper" msg:"BackgroundJob starting" attr:{"threadName":"WTIdleSessionSweeper"}}         
    s:"D1"  "c":"STORAGE""id":22303 "ctx":"WTIdleSessionSweeper" msg:"starting {name} thread" attr:{"name":"WTIdleSessionSweeper"}}         
    s:"I""c":"STORAGE""id":4366408  "ctx":"initandlisten" msg:"No table logging settings modifications are required for existing WiredTiger tables" attr:{"loggingEnabled":true}}         
    s:"D1"  "c":"STORAGE""id":20280 "ctx":"initandlisten" msg:"Registering collection" attr:{"namespace":"admin.system.version" uuid:{"uuid":{"$uuid":"df2f047f-4856-4141-8194-4d992c7510e2"}}}}        
    s:"D1"  "c":"STORAGE""id":5255601  "ctx":"initandlisten" msg:"Finished writing to the CollectionCatalog" attr:{"jobs":1}}         
    s:"D1"  "c":"STORAGE""id":20280 "ctx":"initandlisten" msg:"Registering collection" attr:{"namespace":"local.startup_log" uuid:{"uuid":{"$uuid":"9412d283-f2d8-4e83-911e-46c363a8f0f6"}}}}        
    s:"D1"  "c":"STORAGE""id":5255601  "ctx":"initandlisten" msg:"Finished writing to the CollectionCatalog" attr:{"jobs":1}}         
    s:"D1"  "c":"STORAGE""id":20280 "ctx":"initandlisten" msg:"Registering collection" attr:{"namespace":"config.system.sessions" uuid:{"uuid":{"$uuid":"bec45c5a-6b71-4a1a-94e6-ab2393a4dcaf"}}}}        
    s:"D1"  "c":"STORAGE""id":5255601  "ctx":"initandlisten" msg:"Finished writing to the CollectionCatalog" attr:{"jobs":1}}         
    s:"I""c":"STORAGE""id":22262 "ctx":"initandlisten" msg:"Timestamp monitor starting"}          
    s:"D1"  "c":"STORAGE""id":22275 "ctx":"initandlisten" msg:"flushing directory {dir_string}" attr:{"dir_string":"/dbpath/db9999"}}         
    s:"D1"  "c":"COMMAND""id":23098 "ctx":"JournalFlusher" msg:"BackgroundJob starting" attr:{"threadName":"JournalFlusher"}}         
    s:"W""c":"CONTROL""id":22138 "ctx":"initandlisten" msg:"You are running this process as the root user  which is not recommended" tags:["startupWarnings"]}        
    s:"D1"  "c":"STORAGE""id":4584701  "ctx":"JournalFlusher" msg:"starting {name} thread" attr:{"name":"JournalFlusher"}}         
    s:"D1"  "c":"COMMAND""id":23098 "ctx":"Checkpointer" msg:"BackgroundJob starting" attr:{"threadName":"Checkpointer"}}         
    s:"D1"  "c":"STORAGE""id":22307 "ctx":"Checkpointer" msg:"Starting thread" attr:{"threadName":"Checkpointer"}}         
    s:"D1"  "c":"-"      "id":22546 "ctx":"initandlisten" msg:"Reloading view catalog for database" attr:{"db":"admin"}}         
    s:"D1"  "c":"STORAGE""id":5255601  "ctx":"initandlisten" msg:"Finished writing to the CollectionCatalog" attr:{"jobs":1}}         
    s:"I""c":"NETWORK""id":4915702  "ctx":"initandlisten" msg:"Updated wire specification" attr:{"oldSpec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0 maxWireVersion:13} incomingInternalClient:{"minWireVersion":0 maxWireVersion:13} outgoing:{"minWireVersion":0 maxWireVersion:13} isInternalClient:true} newSpec:{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0 maxWireVersion:13} incomingInternalClient:{"minWireVersion":13
    s:"I""c":"STORAGE""id":5071100  "ctx":"initandlisten" msg:"Clearing temp directory"}          
    s:"D1"  "c":"-"      "id":22546 "ctx":"initandlisten" msg:"Reloading view catalog for database" attr:{"db":"local"}}         
    s:"D1"  "c":"STORAGE""id":5255601  "ctx":"initandlisten" msg:"Finished writing to the CollectionCatalog" attr:{"jobs":1}}         
    s:"D1"  "c":"STORAGE""id":21010 "ctx":"initandlisten" msg:"    Opening database: {dbName}" attr:{"dbName":"admin"}}         
    s:"D1"  "c":"STORAGE""id":21010 "ctx":"initandlisten" msg:"    Opening database: {dbName}" attr:{"dbName":"config"}}         
    s:"D1"  "c":"-"      "id":22546 "ctx":"initandlisten" msg:"Reloading view catalog for database" attr:{"db":"config"}}         
    s:"D1"  "c":"STORAGE""id":5255601  "ctx":"initandlisten" msg:"Finished writing to the CollectionCatalog" attr:{"jobs":1}}         
    s:"D1"  "c":"STORAGE""id":21010 "ctx":"initandlisten" msg:"    Opening database: {dbName}" attr:{"dbName":"local"}}         
    s:"I""c":"CONTROL""id":20536 "ctx":"initandlisten" msg:"Flow Control is enabled on this deployment"}          
    s:"D1"  "c":"ACCESS" "id":20227 "ctx":"initandlisten" msg:"There were no users to pin  not starting tracker thread"}         
    s:"D1"  "c":"EXECUTOR"  "id":23104 "ctx":"AuthorizationManager-0" msg:"Starting thread" attr:{"threadName":"AuthorizationManager-0" poolName:"AuthorizationManager"}}        
    s:"D1"  "c":"EXECUTOR"  "id":23104 "ctx":"WaitForMajorityServiceThreadPool-0" msg:"Starting thread" attr:{"threadName":"WaitForMajorityServiceThreadPool-0" poolName:"WaitForMajorityServiceThreadPool"}}        
    s:"D1"  "c":"EXECUTOR"  "id":23106 "ctx":"WaitForMajorityServiceThreadPool-0" msg:"Reaping this thread" attr:{"nextThreadRetirementDate":{"$date":"2022-04-05T03:26:32.007Z"}}}         
    s:"I""c":"FTDC"   "id":20625 "ctx":"initandlisten" msg:"Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture" attr:{"dataDirectory":"/dbpath/db9999/diagnostic.data"}}         
    s:"D1"  "c":"EXECUTOR"  "id":23105 "ctx":"WaitForMajorityServiceThreadPool-0" msg:"Shutting down thread" attr:{"threadName":"WaitForMajorityServiceThreadPool-0" poolName:"WaitForMajorityServiceThreadPool"}}        
    s:"D1"  "c":"EXECUTOR"  "id":23104 "ctx":"FreeMonHTTP-0" msg:"Starting thread" attr:{"threadName":"FreeMonHTTP-0" poolName:"FreeMonHTTP"}}        
    s:"I""c":"REPL"   "id":6015317  "ctx":"initandlisten" msg:"Setting new configuration state" attr:{"newState":"ConfigReplicationDisabled" oldState:"ConfigPreStart"}}        
    s:"D1"  "c":"COMMAND""id":23098 "ctx":"TTLMonitor" msg:"BackgroundJob starting" attr:{"threadName":"TTLMonitor"}}         
    s:"D1"  "c":"COMMAND""id":23098 "ctx":"ClientCursorMonitor" msg:"BackgroundJob starting" attr:{"threadName":"ClientCursorMonitor"}}         
    s:"D1"  "c":"COMMAND""id":23098 "ctx":"PeriodicTaskRunner" msg:"BackgroundJob starting" attr:{"threadName":"PeriodicTaskRunner"}}         
    s:"I""c":"COMMAND""id":51803 "ctx":"LogicalSessionCacheRefresh" msg:"Slow query" attr:{"type":"command" ns:"config.system.sessions" command:{"listIndexes":"system.sessions" cursor:{} $db:"config"} numYields:0 reslen:245 locks:{"Global":{"acquireCount":{"r":1}} Mutex:{"acquireCount":{"r":1}}} storage:{}
    s:"D1"  "c":"COMMAND""id":21971 "ctx":"LogicalSessionCacheRefresh" msg:"Note: not profiling because we are in DBDirectClient"}          
    s:"I""c":"COMMAND""id":51803 "ctx":"LogicalSessionCacheReap" msg:"Slow query" attr:{"type":"command" ns:"config.system.sessions" command:{"listIndexes":"system.sessions" cursor:{} $db:"config"} numYields:0 reslen:245 locks:{"Global":{"acquireCount":{"r":1}} Mutex:{"acquireCount":{"r":1}}} storage:{}
    s:"D1"  "c":"EXECUTOR"  "id":23104 "ctx":"ServiceExecutorFixed-0" msg:"Starting thread" attr:{"threadName":"ServiceExecutorFixed-0" poolName:"ServiceExecutorFixed"}}        
    s:"D1"  "c":"COMMAND""id":21971 "ctx":"LogicalSessionCacheReap" msg:"Note: not profiling because we are in DBDirectClient"}          
    s:"I""c":"NETWORK""id":23015 "ctx":"listener" msg:"Listening on" attr:{"address":"/tmp/mongodb-9999.sock"}}         
    s:"I""c":"NETWORK""id":23015 "ctx":"listener" msg:"Listening on" attr:{"address":"XX.XX.XX.XX"}}         
    s:"I""c":"NETWORK""id":23015 "ctx":"listener" msg:"Listening on" attr:{"address":"127.0.0.1"}}         
    s:"I""c":"NETWORK""id":23015 "ctx":"listener" msg:"Listening on" attr:{"address":"127.0.1.1"}}         
    s:"I""c":"NETWORK""id":23016 "ctx":"listener" msg:"Waiting for connections" attr:{"port":9999 ssl:"on"}}        
    s:"I""c":"COMMAND""id":51803 "ctx":"LogicalSessionCacheReap" msg:"Slow query" attr:{"type":"command" ns:"config.transactions" command:{"find":"transactions" filter:{"lastWriteDate":{"$lt":{"$date":"2022-04-05T02:56:02.011Z"}}} projection:{"_id":1} sort:{"_id":1} readConcern:{} $db:"config"} planSummary:"EOF" keysExamined:0
    s:"D1"  "c":"COMMAND""id":21971 "ctx":"LogicalSessionCacheReap" msg:"Note: not profiling because we are in DBDirectClient"}          
    s:"I""c":"CONTROL""id":23377 "ctx":"SignalHandler" msg:"Received signal" attr:{"signal":15 error:"Terminated"}}        
    s:"I""c":"CONTROL""id":23378 "ctx":"SignalHandler" msg:"Signal was sent by kill(2)" attr:{"pid":1 uid:0}}        
    s:"I""c":"CONTROL""id":23381 "ctx":"SignalHandler" msg:"will terminate after current cmd ends"}          
    s:"I""c":"REPL"   "id":4784900  "ctx":"SignalHandler" msg:"Stepping down the ReplicationCoordinator for shutdown" attr:{"waitTimeMillis":15000}}         
    s:"D1"  "c":"-"      "id":23074 "ctx":"SignalHandler" msg:"User assertion" attr:{"error":"NotWritablePrimary: not primary so can't step down" file:"src/mongo/db/repl/replication_coordinator_impl.cpp" line:2587}}       
    s:"I""c":"REPL"   "id":4794602  "ctx":"SignalHandler" msg:"Attempting to enter quiesce mode"}          
    s:"I""c":"COMMAND""id":4784901  "ctx":"SignalHandler" msg:"Shutting down the MirrorMaestro"}          
    s:"I""c":"SHARDING"  "id":4784902  "ctx":"SignalHandler" msg:"Shutting down the WaitForMajorityService"}          
    s:"D1"  "c":"EXECUTOR"  "id":23104 "ctx":"WaitForMajorityServiceThreadPool-1" msg:"Starting thread" attr:{"threadName":"WaitForMajorityServiceThreadPool-1" poolName:"WaitForMajorityServiceThreadPool"}}        
    s:"D1"  "c":"EXECUTOR"  "id":23105 "ctx":"WaitForMajorityServiceThreadPool-1" msg:"Shutting down thread" attr:{"threadName":"WaitForMajorityServiceThreadPool-1" poolName:"WaitForMajorityServiceThreadPool"}}        
    s:"I""c":"CONTROL""id":4784903  "ctx":"SignalHandler" msg:"Shutting down the LogicalSessionCache"}          
    s:"I""c":"NETWORK""id":20562 "ctx":"SignalHandler" msg:"Shutdown: going to close listening sockets"}          
    s:"I""c":"NETWORK""id":23017 "ctx":"listener" msg:"removing socket file" attr:{"path":"/tmp/mongodb-9999.sock"}}         
    s:"I""c":"NETWORK""id":4784905  "ctx":"SignalHandler" msg:"Shutting down the global connection pool"}          
    s:"I""c":"CONTROL""id":4784906  "ctx":"SignalHandler" msg:"Shutting down the FlowControlTicketholder"}          
    s:"I""c":"-"      "id":20520 "ctx":"SignalHandler" msg:"Stopping further Flow Control ticket acquisitions."}          
    s:"I""c":"CONTROL""id":4784908  "ctx":"SignalHandler" msg:"Shutting down the PeriodicThreadToAbortExpiredTransactions"}          
    s:"I""c":"REPL"   "id":4784909  "ctx":"SignalHandler" msg:"Shutting down the ReplicationCoordinator"}          
    s:"I""c":"SHARDING"  "id":4784910  "ctx":"SignalHandler" msg:"Shutting down the ShardingInitializationMongoD"}          
    s:"I""c":"REPL"   "id":4784911  "ctx":"SignalHandler" msg:"Enqueuing the ReplicationStateTransitionLock for shutdown"}          
    s:"I""c":"-"      "id":4784912  "ctx":"SignalHandler" msg:"Killing all operations for shutdown"}          
    s:"I""c":"-"      "id":4695300  "ctx":"SignalHandler" msg:"Interrupted all currently running operations" attr:{"opsKilled":3}}         
    s:"I""c":"TENANT_M"  "id":5093807  "ctx":"SignalHandler" msg:"Shutting down all TenantMigrationAccessBlockers on global shutdown"}          
    s:"I""c":"COMMAND""id":4784913  "ctx":"SignalHandler" msg:"Shutting down all open transactions"}          
    s:"I""c":"REPL"   "id":4784914  "ctx":"SignalHandler" msg:"Acquiring the ReplicationStateTransitionLock for shutdown"}          
    s:"I""c":"INDEX"  "id":4784915  "ctx":"SignalHandler" msg:"Shutting down the IndexBuildsCoordinator"}          
    s:"I""c":"REPL"   "id":4784916  "ctx":"SignalHandler" msg:"Reacquiring the ReplicationStateTransitionLock for shutdown"}          
    s:"I""c":"REPL"   "id":4784917  "ctx":"SignalHandler" msg:"Attempting to mark clean shutdown"}          
    s:"I""c":"NETWORK""id":4784918  "ctx":"SignalHandler" msg:"Shutting down the ReplicaSetMonitor"}          
    s:"I""c":"SHARDING"  "id":4784921  "ctx":"SignalHandler" msg:"Shutting down the MigrationUtilExecutor"}          
    s:"I""c":"ASIO"   "id":22582 "ctx":"MigrationUtil-TaskExecutor" msg:"Killing all outstanding egress activity."}          
    s:"I""c":"COMMAND""id":4784923  "ctx":"SignalHandler" msg:"Shutting down the ServiceEntryPoint"}          
    s:"I""c":"CONTROL""id":4784925  "ctx":"SignalHandler" msg:"Shutting down free monitoring"}          
    s:"I""c":"CONTROL""id":20609 "ctx":"SignalHandler" msg:"Shutting down free monitoring"}          
    s:"I""c":"CONTROL""id":4784927  "ctx":"SignalHandler" msg:"Shutting down the HealthLog"}          
    s:"I""c":"CONTROL""id":4784928  "ctx":"SignalHandler" msg:"Shutting down the TTL monitor"}          
    s:"I""c":"INDEX"  "id":3684100  "ctx":"SignalHandler" msg:"Shutting down TTL collection monitor thread"}          
    s:"I""c":"INDEX"  "id":3684101  "ctx":"SignalHandler" msg:"Finished shutting down TTL collection monitor thread"}          
    s:"I""c":"CONTROL""id":4784929  "ctx":"SignalHandler" msg:"Acquiring the global lock for shutdown"}          
    s:"I""c":"CONTROL""id":4784930  "ctx":"SignalHandler" msg:"Shutting down the storage engine"}          
    s:"I""c":"STORAGE""id":22320 "ctx":"SignalHandler" msg:"Shutting down journal flusher thread"}          
    s:"D1"  "c":"STORAGE""id":4584702  "ctx":"JournalFlusher" msg:"stopping {name} thread" attr:{"name":"JournalFlusher"}}         
    s:"I""c":"STORAGE""id":22321 "ctx":"SignalHandler" msg:"Finished shutting down journal flusher thread"}          
    s:"I""c":"STORAGE""id":22322 "ctx":"SignalHandler" msg:"Shutting down checkpoint thread"}          
    s:"D1"  "c":"STORAGE""id":22309 "ctx":"Checkpointer" msg:"Stopping thread" attr:{"threadName":"Checkpointer" reason:{"code":91 codeName:"ShutdownInProgress" errmsg:"The storage catalog is being closed."}}}      
    s:"I""c":"STORAGE""id":22323 "ctx":"SignalHandler" msg:"Finished shutting down checkpoint thread"}          
    s:"I""c":"STORAGE""id":20282 "ctx":"SignalHandler" msg:"Deregistering all the collections"}          
    s:"D1"  "c":"STORAGE""id":20283 "ctx":"SignalHandler" msg:"Deregistering collection" attr:{"namespace":"config.system.sessions" uuid:{"uuid":{"$uuid":"bec45c5a-6b71-4a1a-94e6-ab2393a4dcaf"}}}}        
    s:"D1"  "c":"STORAGE""id":20283 "ctx":"SignalHandler" msg:"Deregistering collection" attr:{"namespace":"local.startup_log" uuid:{"uuid":{"$uuid":"9412d283-f2d8-4e83-911e-46c363a8f0f6"}}}}        
    s:"D1"  "c":"STORAGE""id":20283 "ctx":"SignalHandler" msg:"Deregistering collection" attr:{"namespace":"admin.system.version" uuid:{"uuid":{"$uuid":"df2f047f-4856-4141-8194-4d992c7510e2"}}}}        
    s:"D1"  "c":"STORAGE""id":5255601  "ctx":"SignalHandler" msg:"Finished writing to the CollectionCatalog" attr:{"jobs":1}}         
    s:"D1"  "c":"STORAGE""id":22395 "ctx":"SignalHandler" msg:"~WiredTigerRecordStore for: {ns}" attr:{"ns":"config.system.sessions"}}         
    s:"D1"  "c":"STORAGE""id":22395 "ctx":"SignalHandler" msg:"~WiredTigerRecordStore for: {ns}" attr:{"ns":"local.startup_log"}}         
    s:"D1"  "c":"STORAGE""id":22395 "ctx":"SignalHandler" msg:"~WiredTigerRecordStore for: {ns}" attr:{"ns":"admin.system.version"}}         
    s:"D1"  "c":"STORAGE""id":22395 "ctx":"SignalHandler" msg:"~WiredTigerRecordStore for: {ns}" attr:{"ns":"_mdb_catalog"}}         
    s:"I""c":"STORAGE""id":22261 "ctx":"SignalHandler" msg:"Timestamp monitor shutting down"}          
    s:"I""c":"STORAGE""id":22317 "ctx":"SignalHandler" msg:"WiredTigerKVEngine shutting down"}          
    s:"I""c":"STORAGE""id":22318 "ctx":"SignalHandler" msg:"Shutting down session sweeper thread"}          
    s:"D1"  "c":"STORAGE""id":22304 "ctx":"WTIdleSessionSweeper" msg:"stopping {name} thread" attr:{"name":"WTIdleSessionSweeper"}}         
    s:"I""c":"STORAGE""id":22319 "ctx":"SignalHandler" msg:"Finished shutting down session sweeper thread"}          
    s:"I""c":"STORAGE""id":4795902  "ctx":"SignalHandler" msg:"Closing WiredTiger" attr:{"closeConfig":"leak_memory=true }}        
    s:"I""c":"STORAGE""id":22430 "ctx":"SignalHandler" msg:"WiredTiger message" attr:{"message":"[1649129162:20775][5502:0x7f22499c0700]  close_ckpt: [WT_VERB_CHECKPOINT_PROGRESS] saving checkpoint snapshot min: 4  snapshot max: 4 snapshot count: 0  oldest timestamp: (0  0)   meta checkpoint timestamp: (0  0) base write gen: 111"}}   
    s:"I""c":"STORAGE""id":4795901  "ctx":"SignalHandler" msg:"WiredTiger closed" attr:{"durationMillis":10}}         
    s:"I""c":"STORAGE""id":22279 "ctx":"SignalHandler" msg:"shutdown: removing fs lock..."}          
    s:"I""c":"-"      "id":4784931  "ctx":"SignalHandler" msg:"Dropping the scope cache for shutdown"}          
    s:"I""c":"FTDC"   "id":4784926  "ctx":"SignalHandler" msg:"Shutting down full-time data capture"}          
    s:"I""c":"FTDC"   "id":20626 "ctx":"SignalHandler" msg:"Shutting down full-time diagnostic data capture"}          
    s:"I""c":"CONTROL""id":20565 "ctx":"SignalHandler" msg:"Now exiting"}          
    s:"D1"  "c":"EXECUTOR"  "id":23105 "ctx":"OCSPManagerHTTP-0" msg:"Shutting down thread" attr:{"threadName":"OCSPManagerHTTP-0" poolName:"OCSPManagerHTTP"}}        
    s:"I""c":"CONTROL""id":23138 "ctx":"SignalHandler" msg:"Shutting down" attr:{"exitCode":0}}
```

```
    systemctl status mongod.service
    ● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
       Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
       Active: failed (Result: start-limit-hit) since Mon 2022-04-04 08:51:19 UTC; 18h ago
         Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
      Process: 27011 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongo/mongodb.conf (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
     Main PID: 27011 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    
    Apr 04 08:51:19 server systemd[1]: mongod.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
    Apr 04 08:51:19 server systemd[1]: mongod.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
    Apr 04 08:51:19 server systemd[1]: Stopped MongoDB Database Server.
    Apr 04 08:51:19 server systemd[1]: mongod.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
    Apr 04 08:51:19 server systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'.
    Apr 04 08:51:19 server systemd[1]: Failed to start MongoDB Database Server.
```

```
    journalctl -u mongod.service    
    systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
    mongod[26662]: about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
    mongod[26662]: forked process: 26676
    mongod[26662]: child process started successfully, parent exiting
    systemd[1]: mongod.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
    systemd[1]: mongod.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.
    systemd[1]: Stopped MongoDB Database Server.
    systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
    mongod[26747]: about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
    mongod[26747]: forked process: 26765
    mongod[26747]: child process started successfully, parent exiting
    systemd[1]: mongod.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
    systemd[1]: mongod.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 2.
    systemd[1]: Stopped MongoDB Database Server.
    systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
    mongod[26840]: about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
    mongod[26840]: forked process: 26858
    mongod[26840]: child process started successfully, parent exiting
    systemd[1]: mongod.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
    systemd[1]: mongod.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 3.
    systemd[1]: Stopped MongoDB Database Server.
    systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
    mongod[26932]: about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
    mongod[26932]: forked process: 26948
    mongod[26932]: child process started successfully, parent exiting
    systemd[1]: mongod.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
    systemd[1]: mongod.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 4.
    systemd[1]: Stopped MongoDB Database Server.
    systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
    mongod[27011]: about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
    mongod[27011]: forked process: 27027
    mongod[27011]: child process started successfully, parent exiting
    systemd[1]: mongod.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
    systemd[1]: mongod.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
    systemd[1]: Stopped MongoDB Database Server.
    systemd[1]: mongod.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
    systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'.
    systemd[1]: Failed to start MongoDB Database Server.
```

Comment: Check directory from where systemd tries to look PID file (/etc/systemd/...) and compare that it's same what your /etc/mongod.conf uses. If systemd cannot find PID file after start, it will kill the process automatically.

Comment: According to `msg:"Received signal" attr:{"signal":15 error:"Terminated"}` service is killed by your operating system, not a failure in mongod itself. What do you get from `systemctl status mongod` or `journalctl -u mongod.service`

Comment: @JJussi pid file is same in both mongodb.conf file and /lib/systemd/system/mongo.service file.

Comment: @Wernfried Domscheit I've added the output of `systemctl status mongod` and `journalctl -u mongod.service`

Comment: replaced log with more verbose log in the question.

Comment: Can you also show the config files `/etc/mongo/mongodb.conf` and `/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service`

Comment: its the basic configuration that I've and default service unit file that I'm using except that following 2 lines: `ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID`
`Restart=always` I even tried commenting out `Restart=always` and `systemctl daemon-reload` but no luck

Comment: This is resolved. Issue was not related to mongodb and it was due to encryption at rest enabled on the host and not letting systemctl to start the service. It was a access restriction for systemctl due to encryption.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue on two different AWS EC2 instances after MongoDb was upgraded to version 5.0.15

Looking through the release notes I found this:

> If you upgrade an existing instance of MongoDB to MongoDB 5.0.15, that
> instance may fail to start if fork: true is set in the mongod.conf
> file.
>
> The upgrade issue affects all MongoDB instances that use .deb or .rpm
> installation packages. Installations that use the tarball (.tgz)
> release or other package types are not affected. For more information,
> see  SERVER-74345.
>
> To remove the fork: true setting, run these commands from a system
> terminal:
>
> ```
> systemctl stop mongod.service
> sed -i.bak '/fork: true/d' /etc/mongod.conf
> systemctl start mongod.service
> ```
>
> The second systemctl command starts the upgraded instance after the
> setting is removed.

Instead of doing the above I simply commented out

```
# fork: true
```

in /etc/mongod.conf and restarted the service.

Source: [MongoDB Upgrade to 5.0 Release Notes](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/release-notes/5.0-upgrade-sharded-cluster/)

Comment: many blessings upon you good sir